# Update multiple entries in an ImmutableJS List

Tags: javascript, list, dictionary, immutable.js

Specifically, I have an ImmutableJS List of Maps, and I want to conditionally update records to the same value (which may include just updating all of them). The use case is revealing mines in minesweeper, when someone loses the game. this is accomplished by setting the `isVisible` tile to true, if `isMine` is also true (or just make every tile visible, regardless of `isMine`)

so my JS schema is like this (where arrays are lists and objects are maps):

```
game = {
  isGameOver: false,
  tiles: [
    {
      isMine: boolean,
      isRevealed: boolean
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

and so what I'm trying to do is, starting with `game`, set `isRevealed` to true for every tile where `isMine` is true.

this is what i came up with, but it looks so awful I have to hope there's another way

```
function revealAll(game){
  let revealedTiles;

  revealedTiles = game.get('tiles').map(tile => {
    if (tile.get('isMine')) {
      tile = tile.set('isRevealed', true);
    }
    return tile;
  });

  return game.set('isGameOver', true).set('tiles', revealedTiles);
}
```

this successfully ends the game (sets `isGameOver` to true) and reveals all tiles that are mines (sets `isRevealed` to true for every tile with `isMine` equal to true), but I can tell just looking at it that its both inefficient and messy. Is there a built in way to accomplish what i'm doing here?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything horribly wrong with it but if you're terribly worried about it, just use .withMutations before you map the list. But really, for a few hundred objects in non-performance-critical code, it seems not worth thinking too hard about.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the code is quite fine :) There are however few tricks that may make it nicer:

using multiple `set` on the same `Map` can be replaced by one `merge`:

```
return game.merge({
    'isGameOver': true,
    'tiles': revealedTiles
});
```

Also, updating an individual tile can be done nicer:

```
revealedTiles = game.get('tiles').map(
    tile => tile.update('isRevealed', (v) => tile.get('isMine') || v))
```

so you end up with:

```
function revealAll(game){
    let revealedTiles

    revealedTiles = game.get('tiles').map(
        tile => tile.update('isRevealed', (v) => tile.get('isMine') || v))

    return game.merge({
        'isGameOver': true,
        'tiles': revealedTiles
    });
}
```

OR, you can do it like this:

```
const revealAll = (game) =>
    game
    .set('isGameOver', true)
    .update('tiles', (tiles) => tiles.map(
        tile => tile.update('isRevealed', (v) => tile.get('isMine') || v)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional programming approach using [mudash](https://github.com/brianneisler/mudash). The benefit of this approach is that mudash will handle both ImmutableJS data types as well as standard JS (or a mix of both). So your function can be used no matter the format.

```
import _ from 'mudash'
import fp from 'mudash/fp'

const revealAll = _.compose(
  fp.set('isGameOver', true),
  fp.update('tiles', fp.map((tile) =>
    _.update(tile, 'isRevealed', (isRevealed) => _.get(tile, 'isMine') || isRevealed)))
)

const gameMutable = {
  isGameOver: false,
  tiles: [
    {
      isMine: false,
      isRevealed: false
    },
    {
      isMine: true,
      isRevealed: false
    },
    {
      isMine: false,
      isRevealed: true
    },
    {
      isMine: true,
      isRevealed: true
    }
  ]
}
const gameImmutable = _.immutable(gameMutable)

console.log(revealAll(gameMutable))
console.log(revealAll(gameImmutable))
```